# soft input keyboard keydown capture not working

Tags: java, android

I am building an app and I need to determine what key has been pressed by the user on the soft input keyboard. I have the following function, the log only gets fired when the enter and back key is pressed - 64 and 67. Nothing happens when any other keys on the keyboard are pressed.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    String f=Integer.toString(keyCode);
    Log.d(TAG, f);
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TextWatcher for getting the currently typed text.

```
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `setOnKeyListener()` method:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked ENTER or END button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Off course, this is an example for Enter key.